# Multiplicative error in survey data

Tags: survey, random-variable, error, methodology

I'm working on a panel survey data where each individual's income was multiplied by a individual-specific random number (each random number is evenly distributed from 0.5 to 1.5) to avoid any participant being recognized from the data. Basically, I cannot directly compare two individual's income using the data. For this type of multiplicative error, I was wondering do I need to use any particular method to correct it? Any advice will be appreciated!

Problem solved. Please see Nestor's answer.

Comment: Yup: use logarithms!

Comment: But you want to study the population, not individuals ;-). The idea is that you measure a number $X_i = C_iI_i$, where $C_i \sim U(0.5,1.5)$, whereas $I_i$ is the income. Thus, using logarithms, you get $\log(X_i) = \log(C_i)+\log(I_i)$, and you can study the new random variable $\log(I_i)$, the logarithm of the incomes, which has an associated 'error' which you now know which shape it has (if $C_i$ is uniformly distributed between $0.5$ and $1.5$, is straightforward to determine the distribution of $\log(C_i)$).

Comment: I'm gonna post it as an answer for further reference ;-). Glad it helped to enlighten your analysis, good luck with it!

Comment: Nestor, a follow-up question, if I want to test the determinants of wage, then the model should look like: log(x_i)= beta*independent variables_i+error_i, what else should I do to make this model look better, other than considering omitted variable bias?

Comment: That's rather specific to your area and not to statistics in general, I would think. In that respect, you are probably more of an expert than I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: logarithms. You want to study the population, not individuals, so transforming you problem into logarithms is one way to go.

The idea is that you measure a number $X=CI$, where $C \sim U(0.5,1.5)$, whereas $I$ is the income. Thus, using logarithms, you get $$\log(X)=\log(C)+\log(I),$$ and you can study the new random variable $\log(I)$, the logarithm of the incomes, which has an associated 'error' which you now know which shape it has (if $C$ is uniformly distributed between 0.5 and 1.5, it is straightforward to determine the distribution of $log(C)$).

Comment: OP should note that log(C) doesn't have a mean of zero, so on the log-scale expectations will be "shifted" on average. (This is unavoidable - it can't be unbiased on both the original and log scale)